# Ember.js - get value of `--proxy` parameter passed into `ember server`

Tags: ember.js

I need my Ember app to make an AJAX request to the API backend it is proxying to. I have some kludgy code that inserts one of several hard-coded values but I'd much rather the AJAX request just grabs the value passed into `--proxy` when I run `ember server`.

Does anyone know if there's a way to retrieve this value from within Ember?

Comment: Why not make the request to an absolute path and let the ember proxy handle it for you?

Comment: @Lux you know, that didn't even occur to me. I tried it and it worked. Thank you! Do you want to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears it is not exposed, at least not by any public API.  If you don't mind a bit of duplication at the command line, this would work:

```sh
$ proxy=http://myproxy ember server --proxy http://myproxy
```

The env params need to come before `ember server` or else ember throws them away.

```js
// app/config/environment.js

const proxy = process.env.proxy;

const ENV = {
  APP: {
    // Here you can pass flags/options to your application instance
    // when it is created
    proxy,
  },
};
```

```js
// app/routes/my-route.js (or wherever)

import ENV from 'myAppName/config/environment';

export default Route.extend({
  model() {
    return ENV.APP.proxy;
  },
});
```

You can of course access `process.env.proxy` from anywhere, but this is cleaner and keeps the property where it belongs.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it in the file `config/environment.js`.

```
const proxy = (process.argv.indexOf('--proxy') != -1) ? process.argv[process.argv.indexOf('--proxy') + 1] : '';
```

Comment: It's also possible that arg is passed like `--proxy=...`, so `process.argv.join(' ').match(/--proxy[ =](\S+)/)[1]` is more universal